# Entrada não está fazendo sentido

Tags: c, arquivo

```
void cadastroturma () {
char turma[30],caminho[100];
printf ("Diga o nome da turma a ser cadastrado:\n");
scanf ("%[^\n]", &turma);//Já tentei com gets e fgets
getchar();//Já tentei sem esse getchar
printf ("\nAgora o caminho onde quer gravar a turma:\n");
scanf ("%[^\n]", &caminho);
getchar();
mkdir(caminho);
strcat(strcat(strcat(caminho,"/"),turma),".coe");
printf("%s", caminho);
FILE *cadastro = fopen (caminho, "ab");
```

Olá, estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade de arquivo, essa é a função de cadastro de turma, ainda não coloquei a entada de alunos mas esse não é o ponto...
O problema é que na saída, de tantas formas que já coloquei, o arquivo criado dentro da pasta ou fica sem nome antes da extensão ou não é criado de forma alguma. Já tentei até com a infame função gets() e não deu certo.
O que quero fazer é entrar com o nome da turma, depois o nome da pasta, criar a pasta e depois juntar os nomes para criar o arquivo dentro da pasta. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

vc errrou no final

```
strcat(strcat(strcat(caminho,"/"),turma),".coe");
printf("%s", caminho);
FILE *cadastro = fopen (caminho, "ab");
```

deveria ser assim:

```
FILE *cadastro = fopen (strcat(strcat(strcat(caminho,"/"),turma),".coe"), "ab");
```

ou colocando dentro da variavel

```
strcpy(caminho, (strcat(strcat(strcat(caminho,"/"),turma),".coe"));
```

Comment: O arquivo tem que ser binário, não precisa colocar o b no final não? De qualquer forma obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: sim precisa do `b` no final

Answer (score 0):

Cara, talvez ao invés de concatenar o nome, você passasse a variável com o nome do diretório, e do arquivo como parâmetro para criá-lo seria mais simples.

Comment: Como assim? Na sintaxe que estudei não achei brecha pra isso, mas você quer dizer colocar como (caminho"/"turma".coe", "ab") ?

Comment: Dessa forma que coloquei não funcionou... assim, o problema não é nem exatamente esse, é que na hora de entrar com os dados, todos os printfs aparecem antes e o arquivo dentro da pasta não era criado com o nome que pedi, apenas a extensão. Agora, com a correção que fiz o arquivo nem é criado...

Comment: Cara digo assim:
caminho = strcat(strcat(strcat(caminho,"/"),turma),".coe");
FILE *cadastro = fopen (caminho, "ab");